# Installation of PostGIS extension not working on a docker image (seems not found by further commands)

Tags: postgresql, postgis, docker

## Context

I have a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) code for installing the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) extension which is working great on my machine but which doesn't work on a docker image. I cannot understand why.

Here are the details.

## Working code (own machine):

Here is the `psql` code on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop with PostgreSQL 10.12 and PostGIS 2.4;

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql (10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select version();
                                                                version                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# create database foo;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \c foo
You are now connected to database "foo" as user "postgres".
foo=# CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
CREATE SCHEMA
foo=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis WITH SCHEMA postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
foo=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION
foo=#
```

Everything went fine.

## Not working code (docker image):

```
$ sudo docker run -d --rm --name pgrouting -e "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" pgrouting/pgrouting:12-3.0-2.6.3
$ sudo docker exec -it pgrouting psql -Upostgres
psql (12.2 (Debian 12.2-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select version();
                                                     version                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# create database foo;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \c foo
You are now connected to database "foo" as user "postgres".
foo=# CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
CREATE SCHEMA
foo=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis WITH SCHEMA postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
foo=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
foo=#
```

The same error appears with this docker image having an older PostgreSQL version (`9.6`): [kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/), so it's not a PostgreSQL 12 issue.

I didn't remember having made fancy installation steps; the PostGIS I installed on my machine was simply installed using `apt`. Same for PostgreSQL.

## Question

What could be wrong here, why is my own installation working out-of-the box and not the docker images?

*May* be related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361715/strange-postgis-errors-after-having-altered-its-extension-by-specifying-the-post

## Edits:

Here is the content of the `postgis_topology.control` file on my laptop:

```
$ cat /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/postgis_topology.control 
# postgis topology extension
comment = 'PostGIS topology spatial types and functions'
default_version = '2.4.4'
relocatable = false
schema = topology
requires = postgis
```

And this is the content of the same file but on the docker image:

```
# cat /usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology.control
# postgis topology extension
comment = 'PostGIS topology spatial types and functions'
default_version = '3.0.0'
relocatable = false
schema = topology
requires = postgis
```

Comment: That is strange. Ever since the extension feature was implemented, `CREATE EXTENSION` has set the `search_path` to the extension schema plus the schemas of all requisite extensions (in that case PostGIS). Perhaps you are using some nonstandard, buggy version of PostgreSQL? What is in `postgis_topology.control`? Does it list `postgis` as a dependency?

Comment: Yes it does list postgis in `Requires` (see edit). My PostgreSQL/PostGIS both come from the official Ubuntu repositories (installed with `apt`).

Comment: It seems that after having installed the `postgis` extension on postgre in the docker image, the `postgis` schema is not in the `search_path`. But it *is* on my laptop because it was already defined for another database (it seems that it reuses the same `search_path` for the newly created `foo` database, which is strange to be, but that's why the `postgis` schema is actually found on my machine and not in the docker images)

Comment: No, the `search_path` is irrelevant. `CREATE EXTENSION` forces the `search_path` to only include the extension schema and the schemas of requisite extensions.